# Using SSL for Azure CDN with a custom domain name

Tags: azure, ssl, cdn

I would like to use my wildcard SSL certificate with a custom domain for my Azure CDN. Everything I'm finding says this is not yet possible, including other questions on Stack Overflow. The questions I'm seeing are at least 6 months old, though, and Microsoft has been iterating Azure at a tremendous pace. Perhaps there's a solution I've lost in the noise?

Comment: UPDATE: As of 19 Jan 2016, this is being worked on with an ETA of Q1 2016. (see link in @Valentin Petkov post)

Comment: According to [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169397-cdn/suggestions/1332683-allow-https-for-custom-cdn-domain-names), it's scheduled to Q4 2016

Comment: Aaand it did not happen, no updates since July.

Answer (score 5):

6.5 years I was waiting for this... finally!!!!
This is now generally available for Azure CDN from Verizon profiles. See the following blog post for details:
 https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-custom-domain-https-support-with-azure-cdn/

Use the following request to vote for this support for Azure CDN from Akamai profiles – 
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169397-cdn/suggestions/18013657-custom-domain-https-support-for-azure-cdn-from-aka

OLD answer:
PLEASE VOTE HERE

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169397-cdn/suggestions/1332683-allow-https-for-custom-cdn-domain-names

see the comment... but still VOTE because Amazon and Rackspace have it from long time!!!

LANNED  ·   Anton Kucer [MSFT]
ADMIN
Anton Kucer [MSFT] (Senior Program Manager, Microsoft Azure) responded

Significant work has been completed on this. The target date for availability, however, has slipped out to Q2 2016. This still remains a top priority for us to complete as early as possible.

·  Jun 5, 2015
**This is targeted for availability later this year.** I’ve updated the title to reflect that this is tracking support for HTTPS for custom CDN domains as support for HTTPS when directly using the CDN endpoint URL – e.g. azXXXX.vo.msecnd.net has been available for several years.

Comment: Done. Now let's see when it happens.

Comment: this above link is not what is asked in question
they do not allow pre owned ssl certificates till date

Answer (score 3):

Azure have just enabled HTTPS for their CDN.

In the portal head to CDN, click on your Endpoint. Then click Custom Domains which opens a new blade. [Add your custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-map-content-to-custom-domain) if have not already done so.

Once added then click on the custom domain and another blade will open with an off/on toggle switch. Switch to on and await your verification email. Ensure you have access to admin@.com as that's where the email is sent. It took around 12 hours from clicking the link in the verification email to finally be enabled.

Hope this helps somebody

Comment: For anybody interested, there's a bit more info here - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/announcing-custom-domain-https-support-with-azure-cdn/

Comment: we can not use our own SSL certificates yet...
they force you to buy one

Answer (score 1):

Sorry Jereme, this functionality is still not available.  It is being worked on, but right now there is no ETA.